# Can't get critical section to be atomic

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I'm currently learning about critical section & semaphores and I'm stuck atm with this part. I hope you guys can give me an insight.

I have these 3 types of threads: one will do pop() on a stack, another does push() on the same stack and the last one prints the values of that stack. At the moment, I've put wait() and signal() on what I assumed as critical sections.

```
class Example{

  public static void main(){

    //create thread objects
    StackPop p1 = new StackPop();
    StackPop p2 = new StackPop();
    StackPop p3 = new StackPop();

    StackPush ps1 = new StackPush();
    StackPush ps2 = new StackPush();
    StackPush ps3 = new StackPush();

    StackValues s1 = new StackValues();
    StackValues s2 = new StackValues();
    StackValues s3 = new StackValues();

    //then we start these threads in mix orders

    p1.start();
    s3.start();
    ps2.start();
    // etc
  }
}

class StackPop extends Thread{

  public void run(){

    mutex.wait();
    pop();
    SOP("value popped is " + get.popVal); 
    mutex.signal();

  }
}

class StackPush extends Thread{

  public void run(){

    mutex.wait();
    push();
    SOP("value inserted is " + get.pushVal);
    mutex.signal();

  }
}

class StackValues extends Thread{

  public void run(){

    mutex.wait();

    for(int i = 0; i<stack.size(); i++)
        S.O.P.("["+getVal(i)+"]");   //where getVal() will retrieve value at that index

    mutex.signal();
  }
}
```

The above code is a simplified version, but the idea is the same. My problem is even though I used wait() and signal(), I still get a really weird output. For example part of my output will show "[1][2][3] value inserted is 3 [5][@][@]" (where @ means no number inside). I realize this is because the processor is letting another thread run while the for loop is getting the value. I was assuming wait() and signal() will make it atomic automatically but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Sorry, what are you using as mutex?

Comment: do you mean how I declared it? I did: Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

Answer (score 1):

You can use locks or "synchronized" on your critical section. You can see more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html
You can use the same idea to pop() push() ect..

With mutex;

```
try {
     mutex.acquire();
     try
     { 
     // work
     } finally {
     mutex.release();
  }
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {// ...}
```

source -> http://java.dzone.com/articles/dnp-java-concurrency-–-part-4

"I have these 3 types of threads: one will do pop() on a stack, another does push() on the same stack and the last one prints the values of that stack"

You are using 3 different stack on for each Thread, thats why you have a unexpected. You make pop on one stack, you push from different stack and finally you print from a another stack.

You should do something like :

```
public class Teste {

    Thread t1;
    Thread t2;
    Thread t3;

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack <Integer>();
    private final Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

    public Teste ()
    {
        Runnable r1 = new Runnable()                                                    
        {                                   
            public void run()
            {
            pop();
            } // run()
        }; // runnable


        Runnable r2 = new Runnable()                                                    
        {                   
            public void run()
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                   push(x);
            } // run()
        }; // runnable

        Runnable r3 = new Runnable()                                                    
        {                   
            public void run()
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                   print();
            } // run()
        }; // runnable

        this.t1 = new Thread(r1); // Create the thread associating the runnable
        this.t2 = new Thread(r2);
        this.t3 = new Thread(r3);
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        try {
            mutex.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stack.pop();
        mutex.release();
    }

    // Similar to pop
    public void push(int x){ //..}

    public void print(){
        try {
            mutex.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        for(int i = 0; i<stack.size(); i++)
            System.out.println("["+stack.get(i)+"]");

        mutex.release();
    }

}

public static void main(String argv[])
  {

    Teste t = new Teste();
    t.t2.start();
    t.t1.start();
    t.t3.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, wait is inherited from Object, its opposite is notify - you are likely to be calling the wrong methods.

Also, Java has a native synchronization mechanism, the synchronized keyword, you may want to investigate that.

Comment: I did use P() and V() which links to the right wait and signal. The output didn't differ a lot...I still had statements printing in wrong places

Comment: You have to use mutex.acquire and mutex.relase http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: is there another solution u can think of without using those 2 methods? I was given a Semaphore class that doesn't contain those methods

Comment: OK is it not a java class? the only thing I can think of is you have multiple instances.

Comment: also, can you post the source of this semaphore class?

Comment: It is a java class similar to Semaphore class in library...I just meant the class didn't contain those 2 methods and they hinted to use wait and signal to make it atomic

Comment: I ask because the "wait()" is defined in Object, and it is not overridable. And, while the default "wait" is the right way to implement a semaphore, using it alone (as in mutex.wait()) it is an incorrect use. Can you please try to see if your code displays the same problem using the Java Semaphore? This will highlight if you are using your own Semaphore (whioch I assume to be implemented correctly) in an incorrect way

Comment: Another **essential** think you have to do is to put the "release" in a finally block. If your code throws an unexpected exception the lock will not be released

Comment: Yep...I did edit the code and put 'signal' in finally block. And the Semaphore class I used have wait() from Object class. I found out why the output is weird everytime(turns out I shouldn't assume execution of threads will go in order) which is why I have broken sentences in output. But I think it's atomic when I ignore those weird sentences and focus on data. Thanks for your inputs.